# Flask - 405 Method not allowed with methods=['GET, POST']

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

```
bp_booking = Blueprint('booking', __name__, url_prefix='/booking', template_folder='templates/booking')

@bp_booking.route('<screening>',  methods=["GET", "POST"])
def seat_select(screening):
    cur = db.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT M.title, S.Screening_Start
                    FROM screening S JOIN movie M ON s.movie_id = M.id
                    WHERE S.id = (%s)""", (screening,))
    screening_details = cur.fetchone()
    title = screening_details[0]
    time = screening_details[1].strftime('%d %B  %H:%M')
    cur.execute("""SELECT A.row_count, A.column_count
                    FROM auditorium A JOIN screening S on S.auditorium_id = A.id
                    WHERE S.id = (%s)""", (screening,))
    screen_no = cur.fetchone()
    row = screen_no[0]
    column = screen_no[1]

   
    return render_template('booking/seatSelect.html', screeningId=screening,
                           title=title, time=time, rows=row, columns=column)


@bp_booking.route('/process-ticket', methods=['GET, POST'])
def process_ticket():
    ticket_value = request.form.get('hidden-ticket-value')
    ## insert into database here
    return 'Ticket inserted into database'
```

**seatSelect.html**

```
<div id="container">
</div>

<div id = "right">
<p id= "quantity">
 Select your seats!
 </p>

    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('booking.process_ticket') }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="hidden-ticket-value">

    <input type="submit" value="Book" id="book-btn">
    </form>

</div>

</body>
```

seatSelect.html has some additonal javascript and css to make a seating plan and the selected seats are stored in the hidden field's value.

When clicking submit I want to get routed to process-ticket 
`<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('booking.process_ticket') }}">` 
but instead the `seat_select(screening)` function called called again with the parameter `screening=process-ticket`
This just throws and error because my function expects a number. Any idea why this is happening?

I tried hardcoding the HTML to take the URL for `process_ticket()` and the same thing happens.

Edit: I changed the route of `select_seat()` slightly and now `process_ticket()` seems to be running but i'm getting a 405 method not allowed error. Should this be happening if `methods=['GET, POST']` is present in the function?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful iformaion.

Comment: if you want number then you may need `<screening:integer>` OR maybe put `def process_ticket()` before `def seat_select()` because address `/process-ticket` can match to `<screening>` and it will use `seat_select()` as first matching route.

Comment: Change `methods=['GET, POST']` to `methods=['GET', 'POST']`

Comment: @furas putting /<screening> gives me the same error ( seat_select(screening) function called called again with the parameter screening=process-ticket) , foo/<screening> on the other hand gives the 405 method not allowed eror. I will do so in future but there Isn't a traceback for the 405 Method not allowed.

Comment: as for me poblem can be because `<screening>` can match any string - even `/process-ticket` - so flask first check address `/process-ticket` with `route("<screening>"` and it match so it doesn't check with `route("/process-ticket")` but runs `seat_select(screening="process-ticket")`. You have to put function `def process_ticket()` before `def seat_select` and flask will check address `/process-ticket` with  `route("/process-ticket")`. OR you should use `<int:screening>` and then address `/process-ticket` will not match to `<int:screening>`

Comment: @vremes Oh yeah my bad, thanks

Comment: @furas Ah i see. Very helpful, thank you

Comment: If someone posts an answer i can accept it but I don't know what's normal on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me poblem can be because `<screening>` can match any string - even `/process-ticket` - and `route("<screening>"...)` is check as first - before `route("/process-ticket")`

Flask first compares address `/process-ticket` with `route("<screening>"...)` and it matches so it doesn't check with `route("/process-ticket")` but runs `seat_select(screening="process-ticket")`.

You have to put function `def process_ticket()` before `def seat_select()` and then flask will check address `/process-ticket` with `route("/process-ticket")` as first.

Or you should use `<int:screening>` to match only number and then address `/process-ticket` will not match to `<int:screening>`